# How can I clone an object in 3dsmax by maxscript without pop-out menu?

Tags: 3dsmax

How can I clone an object in 3dsmax by maxscript without showing the popup dialog?

The macro printed in maxscript listener when doing it manually is:

```
actionMan.executeAction 0 \" 40213\"  -- Edit: Clone
maxOps.cloneNodes $ cloneType:# instance newNodes:&nnl
```

There is a menu to choose the name of the new object, can I assign the name?

I know something like `#noPromt` can be used when Importing `.3ds` files.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me without any dialog. I also added so that you can clone any number of selected objects, it will rename then uniquely, and add a number to the back of them (001,002 and so on). Just change the "changethis" to whatever you like.

```
--clone the selected objects
maxOps.cloneNodes (selection as array) cloneType:#instance newNodes:&nnl #nodialog

--Loop through the array of object it returns
for i = 1 to nnl.count do
(
    --rename the objects to a unique name
    nnl[i].name = uniqueName "changethis" numDigits:3
)
```

Comment: hi, how can I assign the value of the number nnl.count?

Comment: how to create a group, and give it a name? :)
`select # ($RH_sword_078, $RH_sword_079)
actionMan.executeAction 0 "40140"-- Groups : Group`.

Comment: group (selection as array) name:"your_group_name"

If you want it into your clone script, then add this line to the end of the script: group nnl name:nnl[1].name

Answer (score 1):

One line solution

```
newNodes = for myobj in (selection as array) collect (instance myobj )
```

Change *instance* to  *copy*  or *reference*  for clone type